# Change run parameters of Databricks python_wheel_task with CLI

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, python-wheel, databricks-cli

I have created a job in DataBricks. Now, I'm trying to run it using databricks cli. See part of the job json:

```
"tasks": [
    {
        "task_key": "task_key",
        "python_wheel_task": {
            "package_name": "package_name",
            "entry_point": "entry_point",
            "parameters": [
                "command",
                "parameter1",
            ]
        },
        "libraries": [
            {
                "whl": "dbfs:/wheels/anme.whl"
        }
]
```

Command I'm using to run the job (this command works):

```
databricks jobs run-now --job-id 1111
```

Then, I try to change `parameter1` by running

```
databricks jobs run-now --job-id 1111 --python-params '"["value1", "value2"]"'
```

But I get error:

```
Error: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

how can I provide new parameters to python_wheel_task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top the answer from Alex, I found that we have to use escape symbols for command to work.

the solution is:

```
databricks jobs run-now --job-id 1111 --python-params '[\"value1\", \"value2\"]'
```

Comment: Hmmmm, something is wrong then in CLI... let me ping developers, because API says that it's array of strings: https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsRunNow

Comment: You can take a look at this article, where author describes similar issue I'm facing:
https://endjin.com/blog/2019/07/azure-databricks-cli-error-jsondecodeerror-expecting-property-name-enclosed-in-double-quotes

Comment: @AlexOtt do you have any update from developers?

Comment: file github issue at databricks-cli repos

Answer (score 0):

The value for `--python-params` should be JSON array of strings.  In your case you don't need the double quotes around array - just use `'["value1", "value2"]'`.

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for the answer. Can you please explain what you mean by JSON array of strings, and how should I format the input?

 Error: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: Alex, I fixed the error with escape symbols. please see my answer as post